# recovering data on lost partition

Tags: partitioning, file-recovery

I lost a partition (Windows), was able to recover it, but it is not recognized as formatted.

What would be the best way to recover it
(A lot of free tools seems to have a 1G limit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) should do the trick - follow the [walkthrough there.](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) - You can run it most common OSes, and does a good job as long as the drive's recoverable.

I'd suggest using a linux livedisk - sometimes they can 'see' lost NTFS partitions, and you can do a direct copy off that, and if that fails, testdisk.

Comment: With Minitool Partition Wizard i can actually see my directories (While Windows says it is not formatted).

I think they have tools for recovery, but the free versions have a 1G limit.

(The Testdisk examples doesn't cover exactly my situation as far as I can see, but I continue to look at it)

Comment: Solved.  There is a option to recover the boot-sector.

(Undelete will merely copy the files somewhere else)