# How to partition from unallocated space?

Tags: partitioning, recovery

I accidentally deleted my D drive and again created a new volume from that unallocated space and at last, again deleted that new volume.
I want my old D drive back... How?
I want to recover 111 GB

## Plz Help

Comment: "I want my old D drive back" - Given your actions, data recovery will likely be impossible.  The multiple partition removals were the action that makes data recovery nearly impossible.

Comment: If the data are important, you'd better go for paid data recovery services, do this by your self has a chance to destroy more data.

Comment: The probability of data recovering depends on whether the newly created disk was formatted or not, and in general on how and by what method/tool it was done. If the disk was not formatted during the operations described above, the probability of recovery is quite high.

Comment: Search before posting a new question. This has been asked & answered many times before. https://superuser.com/search?q=recover+partition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recovering data on lost partition](https://superuser.com/questions/337666/recovering-data-on-lost-partition)

Answer (score -1):

You can try data recovery softwares like EaseUs data recovery, recuva, wondershare liveboot 2012. But most of them are paid so you may need to buy a license.